# Fetching Private Submodules in AWS Amplify Build

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, git-submodules, aws-amplify

I am deploying my app using AWS Amplify. I decided to separate my a part of my app into a submodule. Now, when I build run `git submodule update --init --recursive` in the build of Amplify, it gives me an access error since it is a private repository and AWS could not access it.

I have two choices, one is using the `https` to fetch the repo, but it will require me to put my username and password in the submodule. Or figure out a way for AWS to generate an SSH key that I can pair to the submodule SSH access to proceed. I would like to use the latter, but I have no idea how to do it in AWS Amplify.

Answer (score 5):

It seems one solution would be to generate an SSH key without a passphrase *(insecure solution)* and then add it as an environment variable in the aws-amplify project:

1. Generate a ssh key without passphrase:

- `ssh-keygen -f deploy_key -N ""`
- Copy the base64 encoded content of your private key `cat deploy_key | base64 -w0` into your Amplify project environment variable. Eg. DEPLOY_KEY
- Copy the content of your public key `cat deploy_key.pub` to your ~/.ssh/authorized_keys (depending on your repository provider, Access keys in Repository settings for Bitbucket in our case)

2. In the preBuild or build section of your amplify.yml add the following :

```
commands:
        - eval $(ssh-agent -s)
        - ssh-add <(echo "$DEPLOY_KEY" | base64 --decode)
```

Comment: It seems the clone occurs before the `preBuild` phase - so the build fails before I can even inject the SSH key

Comment: sorry for the late question, but where will I find `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` in my repository or in Amplify settings?

Comment: This no longer seems to be working

Answer (score 2):

Spoke to AWS about this issue as well, and there is no solution at the moment for the second option.

You could create a separate GitHub user with read-only access to the submodule repo, and add it via HTTPS: `https://USERNAME:PASSWORD@github.com/ACCOUNT/SUBMOUDLE-REPO.git`

Bonus: If you would like to push changes to the submodule repo, you can change the origin push URL. Within the submodule directory: `git config remote.origin.pushurl git@github.com:ACCOUNT/SUBMODULE-REPO.git`

FWIW, Netlify had the same issue a few months ago (not sure if it's still the case), their work-around would be for them to manually generate a deploy key for the submodule repo, but due to GitHub's restrictions this key would only work once - meaning for any other repo/site that needed to use the submodule you would need to go through the process again.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. I just went and did what you mentioned and created a separate user with read-only access. Also, rather than use submodules, I just created an npm package and just